# Images on website working on windows, not on linux

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a website on windows and transfered them to my linux pc. Server is hosted through xampp and the directories should work, as the website is correctly displayed with exception of the images loading from a seperate folder (/img/weboptimized/image.jpg). On windows everything worked, code didn't change. But on Linux the Images are not displayed and this broken image symbole appears.Any suggestions why images are broken?? thank you a lot .

I'm not really comfortable with linux yet..still need a lot to learn.

image is called in my html like this:

```
<img src="img/weboptimized/conference.jpg" class="list-entry-img">
```

Comment: Verify that the names match exactly (upper and lower case). I've seen this issue in the past because UNIX/Linux is case sensitive while Windows isn't.

Comment: So many things to check :) right click your broken image and select "open in new tab". Does the complete url make sense to you ? If it does, are the files actually there?

Comment: well, you both were right! the file paths were wrong, and also the case sensitivity was causing problems! thank you guys!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you haven't specified the path to the images using the exact capitalization of the Linux file system. Windows is not case-sensitive, so mismatches with case won't affect the server's ability to locate the file properly. But, with Unix/Linux, folder and file name differ by case.

Comment: yea the capitalization was the issue I've had. didnt know this was a thing on linux:) thank you !